# toggleClass flickering on mouse movement

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

http://esp-platform.ice.im/

See the URL above and hover over the down arrow or search icon in the top right.
When hovering over this li with class `cp-dropdown` i want to toggle the class `showme` however for some reason whilst you move the mouse the class seems to flicker ? Does anyone have any ideas?

Jquery Used:

```
function navShow() {
  $('.cp-dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.site_tint').toggleClass('showme');
  });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @james246 above i was able to fix this problem pretty easily, i've tweaked his code to get a thorough fix for this; i basically needed to apply the same `z-index` as the child div on my dropdown menu. See my additions below:

```
function navShow() {
  $('.cp-dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.site_tint').addClass('showme');
    $(this).addClass('current')
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.site_tint').removeClass('showme');
    $(this).removeClass('current')
  });
}
```

Hope this helps, see the url in the question for a working example :)

Answer (score 2):

The `mouseenter` event is firing over and over, therefore toggling your class continuously. Implement `mouseleave` to remove the class:

```
function navShow() {
  $('.cp-dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.site_tint').addClass('showme');
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.site_tint').removeClass('showme');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate i'll implement this later on and let you know the result! :]

Comment: thank you mate, took me 2 mins to tweak your code to answer this issue, see my edit below :)